# Lebesgue Integral-Question

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, simple-functions

[image: C, Cantor Set.]
Hi guys,
How can I evaluate Lebesgue Integral of this function. I think first I should show that is simple function ?

Comment: Erm, what is $C$?

Comment: @ClementC. Ups :) C is Cantor set

Comment: Do you know the Lebesgue measure of the Cantor set? Of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: So $C$ is measurable and has zero measure... In particular, $\int_{C\cap \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}} 2d\lambda = 0$.

Comment: @ClementC. What about the measures of C intersection R\Q and [0,1]\C ?

Comment: Since $\mu(C)=0$, and $\mu(\mathbb{Q})=0$, then $\mu(C \cap \mathbb{Q})=0$, as well as $\mu(C \cap \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q})=0$. Then, the integral is taken over the subset $I \cap C$, which has the measure 1.

Comment: If $\lambda(C)=0$, then $\lambda(C\cap (\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})) \leq \lambda(C)=0$. @YücelYarım

Comment: So lebesgue integral of this function is 3. In addition, this f(x) is simple function right? These domains are disjoint and f(x) has different values on each domain so this is simple function. Right?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean $C$ is the Cantor ternary set, then since $\lambda(C)=0, \lambda(C\cap\mathbb{Q})=0=\lambda(C\cap\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure, $C, \mathbb{R},\mathbb{Q}$ are Borel and hence measurable, $f(x)=\mathbb{1}_{C\cap\mathbb{Q}}(x)+2*\mathbb{1}_{C\cap\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}}(x)+3*\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]\setminus C}(x)$, hence $f$ is simple, and its integral is$ \lambda(C\cap\mathbb{Q})+2\lambda(C\cap\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})+3\lambda([0,1]\setminus C)=3$